# ajax php script error inspite user is being saved to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

i have a simple php script the user is being saved to database (which i can see in phpmyadmin but on client side i get always an error

```
   <?php

   initServer()

   $con = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password) or die ("Could not connect: "                                  .mysql_error());
   echo "connection established successfully";

   mysql_select_db($database, $con);

   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
   $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);

   $sql = "INSERT INTO `$tableName`(`user`, `mail`) VALUES ('$username','$email')";

   if(!mysql_query($sql, $con)){
       die('Error: ' .mysql_error());   
   }else{
       echo "User added";
   }
   mysql_close($con)
   ?>
```

My Javascript:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: postData,
      url: 'login.php',
      success: function(xhr){
          alert(xhr);


      },
      error: function(xhr){

         alert("ooopsie :"+xhr.statusText);
      }
  })
```

});

the error message is being triggerd inspite the user is being saved to database? what could be wrong?

Comment: Fix all the errors in your PHP code.

Comment: show where you define `postData` variable that is being sent. Also, which error message are you refering to?

Comment: `initServer()` needs a semicolon at the end

Comment: What you see in developer console of your browser?